# QML unexpected binding

Tags: qt, qml

Now, while porting my app to Qt 5.9 I've faced some strange behavior. The code describing the issue is below:

```js
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 800
    title: qsTr("Test")

    Row {
        id: base
        property var arr: []
        property color currentColor: "red"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        spacing: 5
        Repeater {
            model: 10
            delegate: Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                border.width: 1
                border.color: "grey"
                color: base.arr[index] === undefined ? "white" : base.arr[index]
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        base.currentColor = Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1);
                        base.arr[index] = base.currentColor;
                        base.arr = base.arr; // trick to fire changing event
                        console.log(base.arr)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So there is array of rectangles and while pressing one of them I get random color and place it in the array `base.arr` at some index as item one. There is a property `base.currentColor` to keep the current color. But the problem is that if I assign new color to an item all previous items change color too.

I guess the problem is in line

```
base.arr[index] = base.currentColor;
```

It looks that this line creates some unexpected binding or reference or whatever I don't see. As I know the only way to create binding in Js is `Qt.binding` but here I don't use that.

The workaround to break this behavior is something like this:

```
base.arr[index] = Qt.rgba(base.currentColor.r, base.currentColor.g, base.currentColor.b, base.currentColor.a);
```

but it looks overhead and dirty solution.

I would be glad if someone can explain this strange behavior.

Answer (score 1):

QML `color` is actually a color `object`.

In JavaScript objects are copied by reference, so a QML `color` variable actually behaves more like a pointer.

On this line:

```
base.arr[index] = base.currentColor;
```

the array element is set as a *reference* to the `currentColor` object.

When each array element is set, it gets set as a reference to the same `currentColor` object! Thus changing the `currentColor` changes every element in the array.

Instead of this:

```
property color currentColor: "red"
```

use this:

```
property string currentColor: "red"
```

strings in QML are always copied by value, so you will no longer have a problem.

Full code:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 800
    title: qsTr("Test")

    Row {
        id: base
        property var arr: []
        property string currentColor: "red"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        spacing: 5
        Repeater {
            model: 10
            delegate: Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                border.width: 1
                border.color: "grey"
                color: base.arr[index] === undefined ? "white" : base.arr[index]
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        base.currentColor = Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1);
                        base.arr[index] = base.currentColor;
                        base.arr = base.arr; // trick to fire changing event
                        console.log(base.arr)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I can't understand is - 
you said you are porting your app to Qt 5.9... If you are porting from a previous version of Qt, then I am surprised that the code did not behave the same way in the previous version.

Comment: Thanks @Mark Ch for the response. All you said is right, but I am concerned about another issue. Assigning reference to object instead of copying its value isn't expected behavior here I guess. And according to your suggestion simple objects behaves different? Part of them assign reference(like `color`) and part copy its values (like `string`)?

Comment: I think you are right to be concerned, it seems like a bug to me. Is this behaviour different on 5.9 than previous versions?